# Sending and recieving plain text instead of an object with node http

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I'm incredibly new at trying to do anything relating to webservers and the like and I've gotten stuck trying to send data from a javascript that runs on a website to a server that runs locally. I've been able to get them to communicate, but all the data I get on the server is always just "[object object]" instead of the string that I send from the browser.

This is how the server is looking currently, very bareboned:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});   
    console.log("request recieved: " + response + request);  
  }).listen(8001);
```

And this is what i send from the browser:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8001";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: "Hello friend",
    contentType: "text/plain",
});
```

I've also tried something like this which results in the same problem:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var sendData = "HELLO";
http.open("POST", "http://localhost:8001", true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
http.send(sendData);
```

I've also tried to use JSON.stringify on the server-side to try to get the string, but this returns an error stating that it cannot be used on a 'circular object'.

I'm sorry if this question is really stupid, as I said, I'm a complete beginner and this is the first time I've tried to do something remotely similar. I've tried researching what to do differently, but after trying countless options I felt that I needed to ask here instead.

Thanks in advance! And if any more information is needed I'd be happy to try to expand on the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `concatenation (+)` operator then javascript will convert `object` to `string`. Default `String`  representation of object is `[object object]`. That's why it's printing `[object object]`.

```
http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});   
    console.log("request recieved: " , response , request);  
  }).listen(8001);
```

And if you want to get the body then you have the listen to `data` event and consume the data.

```
http
  .createServer(function(request, response) {
    let body = "";
    request.on("data", chunk => {
      body += chunk.toString(); // convert Buffer to string
    });
    request.on("end", () => {
      console.log(body);
      response.end('ok');
    });
  })
  .listen(8001);
```

> I will recommend to use `express` package to avoid all boilerplate code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Unfortunately, like the reply from the other user, using 
    console.log("request recieved: " , response , request);
only gives me a whole bunch of data that I have no idea what to do with, and the string I sent from the browser is nowhere to be found within all that. No idea what is going on, maybe something else is breaking it along the way..

Comment: Also, the 


response.on("data", function(chunk) {
      console.log(chunk);
    });


Does not console.log anything at all it seems

Comment: I have update my code, could you please try the updated code . The second block.

Comment: That works perfectly! Ran into some problems with response.end('ok'); due to CORS, but when I commented that out everything worked perfectly! Thanks a lot for taking your time to help a beginner out!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can access the body with `request.body`. You can't `JSON.stringify` the whole request because, as you saw, it holds ciruclar deps, but you can do so with the `request.body`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I tried using request.body but now a whole lof of stuff is getting printed and the string I sent is still not within all of that. And if I try to stringify the request.body I just get "undefined". Maybe I've missed something else

Comment: Please share your outputs!